# Selecting data from various tables without multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

## MySQL - Workbench (PHP):

Tables:

1. TUsers (One to many relationship with TCompanies):

   - TUsers_CompanyID (FOREIGN KEY)
   - TUsers_UserName
   - TUsers_UserPassword
   - TUsers_ID (UNIQUE)
2. TCompanies:

   - TCompanies_CompanyName
   - TCompanies_CompanyContactNumber
   - TCompanies_CompanyAddress
   - TCompanies_ID (UNIQUE)

Is it possible to link multiple tables in a relational database without using the JOIN, or INNER JOIN query commands, without duplicating data in tables?

Thus speaking even another way of creating a relationship that makes the one table "point" to the other's data.

So that one can query the following and successfully retrieve **all** the data from **both** tables at once:

`MySQL:`SELECT * FROM TUsers;

#### See example above..

Comment: You can use subqueries. But `JOIN` was designed exactly for what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without "appearing" to use a join (ie, the word JOIN won't be in the query), but MySQL will still perform a `JOIN`...

```
SELECT *
FROM TUsers, TCompanies 
WHERE TUsers_CompanyID=TCompanies_ID;
```

Comment: +1, but this is called `implicit join` and it is actually a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to escape having to use a `JOIN` for how you want to display your data, but what you might want to do is create what's known as a [VIEW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29), so that you don't actually have to type out the `JOIN` commands whenever you want to query for the user data:

```
CREATE VIEW UsersView AS
SELECT *
FROM TUsers a
INNER JOIN TCompanies b ON a.TUsers_CompanyID = b.TCompanies_ID
```

Then once the view is defined, you can just select from `UsersView` like so:

```
SELECT * FROM UsersView
```

...And it will return the users information ***as well as*** the joined company information. You can think of views as a way to simplify (or "compactify") more complex queries, because underneath the hood, it's actually the same thing as:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM TUsers a
    INNER JOIN TCompanies b ON a.TUsers_CompanyID = b.TCompanies_ID
) UsersView
```